# Rsync file list slow - including dry runs

Tags: rsync

I have been backing up a server over rsync (v3.0.6) for a while. I noticed that it takes about 20 minutes just to get the incremental file list (I am using the whole file flag). I am excluding three files, if I take these out it only takes a second to start syncing. There are only 319 files (689 if you count the directories that get skipped). Any thoughts or ideas? Pattern matching shouldn't be this slow?

```
rsync -vvnWr --exclude='aaa.tar.gz' --exclude='bbb.tar.gz' -exclude='ccc.tar.gz' --include='*.tar.gz' --exclude='*' --delete -e "ssh -p 34577 -i /root/.ssh/backup_rsa" root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/backup/cpbackup/daily/ /backup/jarvis/cpanel/$((($(date +\%-d)-1)/7+1))/*
```

Sample output

```
[sender] showing file ddd.tar.gz because of pattern *.tar.gz
[sender] showing file eee.tar.gz because of pattern *.tar.gz
[sender] hiding directory fff.0 because of pattern *
[sender] showing file ggg.tar.gz because of pattern *.tar.gz
...
```

The output is the same with our without exclusions, obviously it skips the ones I list. With exclusions there are long pauses between each of these. I changed the IP and filenames.

Thanks!

Comment: Why wholefile rather than the default incremental?

Answer (score 2):

I just figured it out, must have needed to sleep on it. I am missing one of the hyphens in an exclude. It must have been reading it as additional parameters without causing any syntax errors, with the -c checksum flag being the one probably causing it to slow down.

Thanks everyone for reading!

Comment: That's an interesting one. The first letter of `-exclude` takes the remaining text as its argument (up to the space). If you hadn't specified `-e` further along the command you'd have seen the error immediately (`rsync: Failed to exec xclude=ccc.tar.gz: No such file or directory (2)`). Oh well.

Comment: [`rsync -e` option documentation](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsync.1#opt-e)

Answer (score 0):

The main reason this is so slow is because you've disabled most of the optimisations that `rsync` has to offer. You're almost at the stage of copying all the included files on every run.

Why? You've mandated `--whole-file` instead of allowing `rsync` to generate differences. You're also not copying the timestamp with `-t` or `-a`, so `rsync` has to read each file on the local and remote systems to determine if the checksums match.

Try this instead

```
rsync --dry-run -vvtr \
    --exclude='aaa.tar.gz' --exclude='bbb.tar.gz' -exclude='ccc.tar.gz' --include='*.tar.gz' --exclude='*' \
    --delete --delete-during \
    -e "ssh -p 34577 -i /root/.ssh/backup_rsa" \
        root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/backup/cpbackup/daily/ \
        /backup/jarvis/cpanel/$((($(date +\%-d)-1)/7+1))/
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! The files are different every time because they are the daily backups for a web/database server. It doesn't explain the reasons its slow only when the excludes are there. I am 100% fine with the speed after that. Do you have any other thoughts with this additional info? Thanks!